# regex to select text between 2 string?

Tags: regex

I've the following string

```
Month: March 2011
Month: January 2012
Month: December 2011
```

and I'd like to write a regex which select the name of the month (ie "March") only for 2011. This mean to select everything between the string "Month: " and the year "2011".
The regex I made is

```
^(Month:)[A-Za-z0-9]+(2011)$
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong???
The results should be "March" and "December".
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookahead:

```
/[a-z]+(?= 2011)/ig
```

See it here in action: http://regex101.com/r/fE9lR9

Here's a JavaScript demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rZJur/

Comment: it works good but it is a little bit hard for me (a real newbie for regex) to understand how it work. It takes everything behind " 2011" but how it excludes the "Month: "?

Comment: @Nicolaesse `[a-z]` only matches characters, so the space between the colon and the month name acts as the barrier.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't matching because you're not accounting for the white space in between the month and the year.

You could capture the month group after accounting for the space:

```
^(?:Month: )([A-Za-z]+)(?: 2011)$
```

Or you could use a look ahead/lookbehind combo:

```
(?<=^Month: )[A-Za-z]+(?= 2011$)
```

Comment: sorry mate but neither the first nor the second regex works for me, have a try at the following http://regex101.com/r/jV2qU8

Comment: You're right, the second one didn't work, I fixed it. But the first one does work, you just need to pull the result from that grouping.

Answer (score 1):

This expression works (look behind / look ahead) `(?<=Month\:\s)(.+?)(?=\s2011)`.

Edit:
With just Non-Capturing groups, this works: `(?:Month\:\s)(.+?)(?:\s2011)`